# Context Switch: Thread vs Process

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, multiprocessing

From what I understand, scheduling is based on processes, not threads. Then let's say I'm running two programs with the same logic, but one with multi-processing(10 processes) and the other one with multi-threading(10 threads). Then, since scheduling is based on processes, wouldn't the program with multi-processing dominate 10/11 of cpu time? The multi-threaded program would only have 1/11 of cpu time and 10 threads share that tiny time slice.

What am I missing?

Comment: You've been reading older textbooks. The scheduler in a modern operating system schedules _threads,_ not processes. The only way that processes enter in to the picture is if the program sets certain process-wide scheduling parameters (e.g., "niceness" in Unix-like operating systems) that the scheduler will take into consideration when it operates on the threads that belong to that process.

Comment: ...assuming that all the threads in all processes are ready/running.